# Implementation of custom message logger for windows : reports 10049 when ntwk cable unplugged

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

Trying to develop a simple/small syslog server for windows.
This implementation is just to store LOGS in the same machine from 2 other processes of same machine.

Wanted this to be similar to LINUX implementation.Started to use UDP DATAGRAM to send data between processes.

It is working as expected. However, it has been noticed that when NETWORK cable is unplugged the messages are not reaching to the server from client process application.

The client process reports 10049 error (When network cable is unplugged)
Request some guidance how to make this work between local process. Since, all my process run in local machine.

SERVER END LISTEN CODE:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    SOCKET s;
    FILE *fp;
    struct sockaddr_in server, si_other;
    int slen , recv_len;
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    WSADATA wsa;
    struct stat sts;
    char fileNameWithPath[512]={'\0'};
    int status;

    printf("ARGC %d\n",argc);
    char a[10];
    strcpy(logBasePath,"C:\\log\\");
    if(argc == 1)
    {
        //parseSyslogConfiguration();
        if (loggingLevel > 4)
            loggingLevel=DEBUG_LOG;

    }
    else
    {
        memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
        strncpy(a,argv[1],1);
        int isnum=isdigit(a[0]);
        printf("len argv : %d , isdigit : %d\n",strlen(argv[1]),isnum);
        //parseSyslogConfiguration();
        if(strlen(argv[1]) == 1 && isnum == 1)
        {

            loggingLevel = atoi(argv[1]);
            if (loggingLevel > 4)
                loggingLevel=DEBUG_LOG;

            printf("Current Log level initaited : %d",loggingLevel);
        }
        else
        {
            loggingLevel=DEBUG_LOG;
            printf("Invalid arg (%s)for syslog server setting log level to DEBUG\n",argv[1]);
            printf("Values can be from : 0-4 \n");
        }
    }

    if(buf[strlen(logBasePath)-1] != '\\')
    {
        printf("ADDING END SLASH\n");
        strncat(logBasePath,"\\",1);
    }
    else
        printf("NOT ADDING END SLASH\n");

    //g_thread_init(NULL);
    //write_mutex = g_mutex_new();
    slen = sizeof(si_other) ;
    getdatetime(&dateinfo);
    strcpy(logFileName,"syslog");
    memset(fileNameWithPath,0,sizeof(fileNameWithPath));
    strcat(fileNameWithPath,logBasePath);
    strcat(fileNameWithPath,logFileName);
    //strcat(fileNameWithPath,logFileName,logBasePath,"syslog");
    status = stat(fileNameWithPath, &sts);
    if(errno == ENOENT)
    {
        fp = fopen(fileNameWithPath, "a+");
        logMessage(fp,dateinfo.syslogTimeFormat,"LOGROTATE","[origin software='TEST']",0);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    getdatetime(&dateinfo);
    setSyslogFileDate(logBasePath);

    //Initialise winsock
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_UNIX , SOCK_DGRAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }
    printf("Socket created.\n");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_UNIX;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( PORT );
    //Bind
    if( bind(s ,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    puts("Bind done");
    //msgQueueId = g_queue_new();
    //g_queue_init(msgQueueId);
  //  syslogFileWriteThreadId = g_thread_create(ProcessLogMsgfunc, NULL, TRUE, &error);
   // syslogRotateThreadId = g_thread_create(syslogRotateMonitor, NULL, TRUE, &error);
    //keep listening for data
    while(1)
    {
        fflush(stdout);
        memset(buf,'\0', BUFLEN);
        if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("recvfrom() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        LOGSTRUCT *qMsg = NULL;
        memset(&message,0,sizeof(LOGSTRUCT));
        qMsg = malloc(sizeof(LOGSTRUCT));
        memset(qMsg,0,sizeof(LOGSTRUCT));
        memcpy(qMsg,&buf,sizeof(LOGSTRUCT));
        PostMessageQ(qMsg);

    }
//  g_mutex_free(write_mutex);
//  g_queue_free(msgQueueId);
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
//    g_thread_join(syslogFileWriteThreadId);
//    g_thread_join(syslogRotateThreadId);
    return 0;
}
```

CLENT SIDE IMPLEMENTATION:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<winsock2.h>
    //#include <glib.h>

    #define DEBUG_LOG 0
    #define TRACE_LOG 1
    #define WARNING_LOG 2
    #define ERROR_LOG 3
    #define FATAL_LOG 4

    #pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

    #define SERVER "127.0.0.1"  //ip address of udp server
    #define BUFLEN 4096  //Max length of buffer
    #define PORT 514   //The port on which to listen for incoming data

    #define RUN_SERVER 1

    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int s;


    GMutex *write_mutex = NULL;

    static char appLogName[128] = {'0'};

    typedef enum{
        LOGINIT,
        LOGMESSAGE,
        LOGTRACE,
        LOGEXIT
    }logCommand;

    typedef struct
    {
        logCommand command;
        int logLevel;
        int pid;
        char appName[128];
        char loggerMessage[3200];
    }LOGSTRUCT, *LPLOGSTRUCT;



    int log_init(char *infoName,int level)
    {
        int ret=0;
        WSADATA wsa;
        //if(write_mutex == NULL)
        //{
            //g_thread_init(NULL);
            //write_mutex = g_mutex_new();
             //Initialise winsock
                if(strlen(infoName) == 0 && strlen(appLogName) == 0)
                {
                    strcpy(appLogName,"ATM");
                }
                else
                {
                    strcpy(appLogName,infoName);
                }


                //create socket
                if ( (s=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    printf("socket() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
                    //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    return -1;
                }
                //int nOpt=1;
                //setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char*)&nOpt, sizeof(int));
                //setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&nOpt, sizeof(int));


                //setup address structure
                memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
                si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
                si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);
                si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
                //si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(SERVER);
               // si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST ;
               // si_other.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;


        //}
        return 0;
    }

    void log_exit()
    {
        RUN_SERVER=0;
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
    }

    void ms_log(char *buf,int priority)
    {
        debug_log(buf,priority);
    }

    void debug_log(char *buf,int priority)
    {
        //g_mutex_lock(write_mutex);
        int ret = 0;
        LOGSTRUCT log;
        memset(&log,0,sizeof(LOGSTRUCT));
        log.command=LOGMESSAGE;
        log.logLevel=priority;
        log.pid = GetCurrentProcessId();
        if(strlen(appLogName))
        {
            strcpy(log.appName,appLogName);
        }
        if(strlen(buf))
        {
            strcpy(log.loggerMessage,buf);
            ret=sendDataPacket(&log , sizeof(LOGSTRUCT));
        }
        //g_mutex_unlock(write_mutex);
    }

    int sendDataPacket(LOGSTRUCT *data , int dataLength)
    {
        BOOL bResult;
        DWORD cbBytes;
        int slen;
        slen=sizeof(si_other);
        if (sendto(s, data, dataLength , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("sendto() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
           return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        char buf[BUFLEN];
        char message[BUFLEN];
        WSADATA wsa;
        LOGSTRUCT log;
        //start communication
        printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
        {
            printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
            //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            return -2;
        }
        printf("Initialised.\n");
        log_init("TESTVEN",1);
        while(RUN_SERVER)
        {
            printf("Enter message : ");
            gets(message);
            log.command = LOGMESSAGE;
            strcpy(log.appName,"TESTAPP");
            log.logLevel=DEBUG_LOG;
            log.pid=GetCurrentProcessId();
            strcpy(log.loggerMessage,message);
            sendDataPacket(&log,sizeof(LOGSTRUCT));
            //send the message
        }
        log_exit();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Exactly which statement is reporting error 10049?  That error is `WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL` and means "Cannot assign requested address.".  I'd say that Windows has de-configured the network when it noticed the cable unplugged and is telling your program that the address in unreachable... except your code shows you're using 127.0.0.1 which should always be reachable.

Comment: @Brain White. The error reads as 'remote address or port is not valid`. How would one side know about remote end? Why would `sendto` throw that error? w.r.t to question here possibly setting server IP address to 127.0.0.1 would help? instead of IP_ADDR_ANY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error code 10049 : WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL:  Cannot assign requested address.

> The requested address is not valid in its context. This normally results from an attempt to bind to an address that is not valid for the local computer. This can also result from connect, sendto, WSAConnect, WSAJoinLeaf, or WSASendTo when the remote address or port is not valid for a remote computer (for example, address or port 0).

So can happen with `sendto` as well. The remote address IP_ADDR_ANY is not a valid address any more on cable plugout?

If its on same machine, try `127.0.0.1` on server code as well?

Comment: Yes that was the issue think it has been solved.. Thanks thought "IP_ADDR_ANY" will automatically bind localhost 127.0.0.1..My bad.